# Make a full screen alertDialog

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-alertdialog

I tried to make a full screen alert dialog. But I have get this [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1WIW.jpg). Please help me to improve it, to full fill the screen. I have read a lot of questions, but I couldn't solve this problem.

Here is my code:

```
    // AlertDialog Builder
    AlertDialog.Builder bmneu = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

    // Inflate
    LayoutInflater inflate = this.getLayoutInflater();

    // View
    View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.help_archive, null);

    // Assign view to AlertDialogBuilder
    bmneu.setView(v);

    // Alert Dialog
    AlertDialog alertHelp = bmneu.create();

    // Show AlertDialog
    alertHelp.show();
```

xml code (help_archive.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#40e9e2f7" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHelpArchive1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="در این قسمت بایگانی از موارد خمسی ذخیره شده را مشاهده می کنید."
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHelpArchive1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/help_archive1"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtArchive2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="تاریخ سال خمسی با مشخص بودن، شمسی و یا قمری بودن سال، مشخص شده است. در سمت چپ تصویر نیز برای حذف، تعبیه شده است."
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHelpArchive2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/help_archive2"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHelpArchive3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="با فشردن کلیدهای زیر می توانید، می توانید مواردی را که قبلا ذخیره کرده اید، مشاهده و یا ارسال کنید."
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHelpArchive3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/help_archive3"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to put marginTop/Bottom to zero in your layout `help_archive`. If this not works then try to set to bmneu.

Comment: In my layout margins are zero. How to set bmenu?

Comment: What are the values in your help_archive layout file

Comment: Please post your xml file **help_archive**

Comment: I think an alertDialog can't be fullScreen. We should use a Dialog instead!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a custom Dialog extending DialogFragment and on your onStart() method to the following:

```
  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        int height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
        int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);

        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful:

```
            AlertDialog.Builder bmneu = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

            // Inflate
            LayoutInflater inflate = getLayoutInflater();

            // View
            View v = inflate.inflate(R.layout.help_archive, null);

            // Assign view to AlertDialogBuilder
            bmneu.setView(v);


            // Alert Dialog
            AlertDialog alertHelp = bmneu.create();

            // Show AlertDialog
            alertHelp.show();

            ScrollView.LayoutParams params = (ScrollView.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            params.width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
```

The last block of code sets the width and height of the view (inside a dialog)

So, put the following code after show `alertHelp.show()` (remember that **v** is your layout):

```
            ScrollView.LayoutParams params = (ScrollView.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
            params.width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Sorry. It couldn't help. I think an alertDialog can't be full screen!

Comment: I could it with this code, try again with the last edition. Only put a code after show dialog.

Comment: No it couldn't help. This code set shifted the elements to right, but the window is not full screen.

Comment: Its very strange, because I created a new project, and I put your code with the "fix" and works perfectly.

Comment: Can you post your project in same repository?, Maybe I can help you.

Comment: No I can't. I used a dialog instead of an alertDialog. Thanks

Comment: If this question is useful, please upvote this question.